# Freemarker JspTagLibs not invoking with Unittest

Tags: java, unit-testing, freemarker

I am trying to unittest a freemarker.ftl file which includes jsptaglib (from the HippoCMS).

It's not working when trying to inlcuding a jsptaglib and gives me a error message.

**Freemarker code;**

---

<#include "include/imports.ftl">

<@hst.setBundle basename="freemarker.test"/>

Hello step4

---

I've tested to see If the template is being mocked and it actually does;

configuration.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(new File("../freemarker"));
final Template template = configuration.getTemplate("Helloworld.ftl");

At this rate I ran the test, and I could see the raw data from the ftl file. To be sure If i actually get data from the template.
So I tried to go a step further and map it (where it goes wrong);

Map model = new HashMap();

/* populate model */

template.process(model, new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));

This is where it goes wrong and gives this error when running the test;

[image: Error]

And the directory for the include is;

<#ftl encoding="UTF-8">
<#assign hst=JspTaglibs["http://www.hippoecm.org/jsp/hst/core"] >

<#assign fmt=JspTaglibs["http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"] >

<@hst.defineObjects />

Im not sure how to fix this issue, I've tried many different attempts but with no luck.

reference;

https://theodoreyoung.wordpress.com/2011/02/19/freemarker-jsp-taglibs-outside-war/#more-227

http://techqa.info/programming/question/20100276/adding-spring-security-jsptaglib-to-a-freemarker-template---issues-with-controller-unit-tests

Some are saying that this issue was fixed in the newest release of freemarker, but dosen't seems thats is the case either.

Comment: HippoCMS certainly invokes templates via `freemarker.ext.servlet.FreemarkerServlet` (or through a subclass of it). That's what adds the `JspTaglibs` variable, and deals with Servlet/JSP integration. Your unit test invokes templates "standalone", so there's no Servlet/JSP support there.

Comment: Can you tell me how to invoke the freemarker.ext.servlet.FreemarkerServlet with unittest?Like a code example of how to do it. I tried to extend the; freemarker.ext.servlet.FreemarkerServlet in the unittest but didn't seem to work either.

Comment: It's pretty much the same issue as unit testing JSP pages or any other Servlet-s; you need a mocked (or a real embedded) Servlet environment. I don't know what's the best for that nowadays, but definitely look for existing solutions (maybe even one HippoCMS offers, if it does, as the templates may want to access CMS features the must be mocked as well).